# Usage of AND vs WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on `PHP page` that connects with `Oracle`. I came across this SQL and I am not sure it is doing what is supposed to, so I thought I would ask here. The SQL in question is like this:

```
select tableA.id, tableA.name, tableB.details 
from tableA
left join tableB on
tableB.id = tableA.id
and 
tableB.logId = '<logged_in_user>'
```

Now when I log in as a user who does not have entries in tableB, I am still getting records when this query runs. And my hypothesis is that instead of `'and'` the clause should have been `'where'`.

```
left join tableB on
    tableB.id = tableA.id
    where
    tableB.logId = '<logged_in_user>'
```

So my two questions are.

1. Am I right?
2. If so, then why does the query return result? what is the `'and'` clause checking?

Could someone explain the difference when using AND vs WHERE in the above query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you haven't told us what tableA and tableB are, or what behaviour you want to see from this query, we can't advise you on what the query *should* be. All we can do is point out that `left join tableB on  ... where tableB.logId = ...` will always be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Am I right?

No. This query:

```
select tableA.id, tableA.name, tableB.details 
from tableA
left join tableB
on tableB.id = tableA.id
and tableB.logId = '<logged_in_user>'
```

Is very different from:

```
select tableA.id, tableA.name, tableB.details 
from tableA
left join tableB
on tableB.id = tableA.id
where tableB.logId = '<logged_in_user>'
```

It's the criteria for joining.

In the first case, you take from A, then join with B when there's a matching id **and** a logId, else leave details null.

In the second, you take from A, then join with B when there's a matching id, else leave details null, *and then you keep only rows from A where there's a B match that has a logId* -- eliminating rows from A in the process, and de facto turning it into an inner join.

Comment: +1 because this is an alternative, but isn't it resolved in a much cleaner fashion leveraging an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: yeah, I was incidentally editing my last paragraph to add that remark. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains a lot.. The only one thing I am still confused about is: In the first one, since logId will not find a match for logged in user, should it not give any results? because the condition `and tableB.logId = '<logged_in_user>'` would not have results?

Comment: @open_sourse, you would need to use `IS NOT NULL` to manage `NULL` values.

Comment: @open_sourse: A left join B means: if B then take stuff from A and B else take stuff from A and null. A inner join B means: take stuff from A and B if and only if there is A *and* B.

Comment: which one is faster query ?

Comment: @alex: picking one over the other for performance reasons is irrelevant, because the two queries are semantically different: the first is a left join, the second is an inner join. from a performance standpoint the left join will usually be slower, but that's basically because it's yielding more rows.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want results with values in both tables what you really want is an **inner join**. Once you have that, it doesn't really matter where you filter results out.

Answer (score 2):

> Now when I log in as a user who does not have entries in tableB, I am still getting records when this query runs.

Simply change the query to use an `inner join` like this:

```
select tableA.id, tableA.name, tableB.details 
from tableA
inner join tableB ...
```

and here is the definition of `left join` from Oracle:

> The LEFT JOIN (also called LEFT OUTER JOIN) keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).

whereas the definition of the `inner join` is:

> The INNER JOIN keyword return rows when there is at least one match in both tables.

Comment: Thank you! I realize that inner join is the way to go here...I am just still trying to wrap my head around why AND clause gave me results - I guess I will have to read more on the joins..

Comment: @open_sourse, because you would need to leverage `IS NOT NULL` to handle `NULL` values -so you'd have to add to your `WHERE` clause.